# nginx returns 499 with 110: Connection timed out in error log

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, timeout, nginx-reverse-proxy

I can't get over the nginx 60s timeout. If I access the node server directly at 8000 it works, through nginx as reverse proxy it always times out after 60s. I have tried every timeout setting I have read on my google journey regarding this problem...

Anyone can help me out here?

Cheers

Minimal steps to reproduce:

```
   server {
     listen 80;
     server_name someserver.net;
 
     location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; 
       proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
       proxy_send_timeout 900s;
       proxy_read_timeout 900s;
       send_timeout 900s;
       client_body_timeout 900s;
       keepalive_timeout 900s;
     }
   }
```

The minimal node.js server:

```
 const http = require('http');
 const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
   const match = req.url.match(/timeout=(\d+)/);
   const timeout = (match ? parseInt(match[1]) || 60 : 60) * 1000;
 
   setTimeout(() => {
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
     res.write('Response');
     res.end();
   }, timeout);

 }).listen(8000, "0.0.0.0");
 
 server.timeout = 15 * 60 * 1000;
```

```
# direct connection: works
curl -v "http://someserver.net:8000?timeout=65"

# timeout of 59s via proxy: works
curl -v "http://someserver.net?timeout=59"
 
# timeout > 60s via proxy: times out
curl -v "http://someserver.net?timeout=61"
```

Answer (score -2):

If anyone ever stumbles over this: it turns out you need to increase

**client_header_timeout**

and/or

**client_body_timeout**

Everything else failed to make it work in my case.